# SQL query to sum two or more columns and displaying them in the other column

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I'm having really hard time trying to make this work. I have this table :
[evid_record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiIIo.png)

Its named evid_record and I want to sum columns : 'Kolokvijum teorija' + 'Kolokvijum zadaci' + 'Aktivnost' + 'Prisustvo' + 'Seminarski rad' + Domaci rad'.

And the result should be displayed in 'Predisp. Obaveza'.

I managed to get it partially work from phpmyadmin/mysql

with this code:

```
SELECT id
     , SUM(teorija + zadaci + akt + pris + semrad + domrad) 
  FROM evid_record 
 GROUP 
    BY id
```

I get the correct results as you can see in the picture :[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciJXS.png)

But I don't know how should I insert that summed data into my column 'Predisp. obaveza'. I'm not even sure if I'm on a right way. I found some similar situations people asked, tried to apply them on my project, and it didnt work..

Comment: Are you wanting to actively insert them into a table/row that exists in the table, or are you just wanting your query output's column name to be `Predisp. obaveza`?

Comment: @Rogue Yes, I'd like them to be inserted(summed and afterwards displayed) in the row that exists in the table and its named Predisp. obaveza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind `SUM` is an aggregate function, it will add the values across all rows. You can simply add the columns together directly.

You're looking for an `UPDATE` statement here, as the data clearly already exists in the table and I don't believe you're inserting new/raw data

```
UPDATE evid_record
SET `Predisp. Obaveza` = (teorija + zadaci + akt + pris + semrad + domrad)
#if you would like to limit the clause, but
#since this is a table-wide function, you can omit it
WHERE evid_record.id = :some-id
```

Comment: It works, I am EXTREMELY thankful Sir! 
I was trying to make this work for hours and hours..

Works like a charm! Many many many thanks once again!

Comment: Keep in mind my comment on the other answer, you should seek to evaluate things like these on-demand, and not store the data redundanty as you'll run into the famous issue of data consistency errors (your "sum column" not matching the sum of the other columns)

Answer (score 0):

Consider storing data like this:

```
id activity score
 1 teorija     10
 1 zadaci       5 
 1 akt          9
 1 pris        12
 1 semrad      10
 1 domrad       2
```

Comment: I suppose that's where it helps to be able to read the language of those variables to know what they are

Comment: @Strawberry I don't know if that would be good since in my first picture/table (evid_record) Ime i Prezime stands for Name and Surname(of a Student) and other stuff is their score on pre-exam activities, and my Professor would probably want it to be as it is right now..

Comment: @Rogue Well, one of them looks like the word 'theory' and another looks like it could be short for 'action', so I just took a stab at it - maybe I'm way off.

Comment: @xfzaero You would normally store that in a separate table.

Comment: A column name containing a dot is a recipe for confusion

Comment: ID stands for ID, Ime for Name(of a Student) Prezime stands for Surname ; Predmet means Subject ; Br index is something that can be safely ignorend in what I need here(just some college id) ; Kolokvijum Theory stands for Theory score on exam ; Kolokvijum Zadaci means Practical part of the exam ; Aktivnost is Activity on class ; Prisustvo means Presence on the classes; and both seminarski and domaci rad are homeworks. I need sum from 'Kolokvijum Teorija' to 'Domaci rad' to be summed and shown @Predisp. Obaveza

Hope that helps, sorry for not translating in the first place

Comment: @xfzaero the things of larger interest were the data values in your `SUM` clause, however what Strawberry is trying to suggest is normalization of your data. Additionally databases should never store something redundantly, at worst you should use a view or temptable.